# Get Spring Principal User From HTTPSession From a Servlet

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a web application that is using Spring 3.* and I have a Flash component inside my web application that needs to POST to a Servlet.  Inside the Servlet's doPost method I want to check the Spring application context to ensure there is an authenticated session, is this possible?

Comment: you want to check current session's authentication(by getting authentication object) or any other authenticated session?

Comment: @Nandkumar - yes I want to get the current session's authentication.

Answer (score 3):

Well it is very simple, just use

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

Comment: auth is null when I try your suggestion.

Comment: do you use Spring's authentication(http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#tech-intro-authentication)?